# Simple filter in symfony when query and controller already exists

Tags: symfony, filter, knppaginator

I have some confusion on how to create a filter with a query and a controller that already exists (with KnpPaginator in it)

I have in my repo a query that search through something, and in my controller two functions `private` called `resultsAction` and a `public` one called `offreAction` that are both together.

Any idea on how to create a simple filter? I followed this [tutorial](https://codereviewvideos.com/course/pagination-filtering-and-sorting/video/simple-filtering-in-twig) but my query already exists in my repo and it didn't work when I applied it.

**My repo**

```
public function getQueryByTypeAndPro($type, User $user, $archive)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder("opn")
        ->andWhere("opn.type = :type")
        ->setParameter("type", $type)
        ->andWhere("opn.resellerId = :reseller")
        ->setParameter("reseller", $user->getId())
        ->andWhere("opn.archive = :archive")
        ->setParameter('archive', $archive)
        ->orderBy("opn.dateCreation", "DESC")
        ->getQuery()
    ;
}
```

**my controller**

```
private function resultsAction(Request $request, User $user, $type, $archive)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');

        $qb = $em->getRepository("STUserBundle:Operation")->getQueryByTypeAndPro($type, $user, $archive);

        $results = $paginator->paginate(
            $qb,
            $request->query->get('page',1),
            $request->query->get('limit',50),
            [
                'defaultSortFieldName'      => 'opn.dateCreation',
                'defaultSortDirection' => 'desc'
            ]
        );

        return array("results" => $results, "archive" => $archive);
    }

public function offreAction(Request $request, User $user, $archive = false)
    {
        return $this->resultsAction($request, $user, Operation::OFFRE_COMMERCIALE, $archive);
    }
```

Should I create a new function (public) in my controller in order to make that work? or can I do it directly in resultsAction where KnpPaginator is ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem.
Here is the answer

Here is my query where I added the filter

```
public function getQueryByTypeAndPro($type, User $user, $archive, $filter)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder("opn")
        ->andWhere("opn.type = :type")
        ->setParameter("type", $type)
        ->andWhere("opn.resellerId = :reseller")
        ->setParameter("reseller", $user->getId())
        ->andWhere("opn.archive = :archive")
        ->setParameter('archive', $archive)
        ->andWhere('opn.vehiculeMarque like :vehiculeMarque')
        ->setParameter('vehiculeMarque', '%' . $filter . '%')
        ->andWhere('opn.id like :id')
        ->setParameter('id', '%' . $filter . '%')
        ->orderBy("opn.dateCreation", "DESC")
        ->getQuery()
    ;
}
```

Here is how I use it in the controller

```
$qb = $em->getRepository("STUserBundle:Operation")->getQueryByTypeAndPro($type, $user, $archive, $filter);
```

and here is how i use it in my view

```
<form action="" method="get">
         <input name="filter" type="text">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Filtrer</button>
</form>
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use findBY function i-e

```
$em->getRepository("STUserBundle:Operation")->findBy(array('type'=>type,'resellerId'=>resellerId,'archive'=>archive),array('dateCreation'=>DESC))
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your help. but it doesn't work. `findBy(array('type'=>type,'resellerId'=>resellerId,'archive'=>archive),array('dateCreation'=>DESC))` show type, resellerId and archive as `undefined constant` I don't really know how can I do

Comment: undefined constant means you did not initialized your variables .Please initialize your variable then it will work for sure.
Just to debug hard coded values of variables.

Comment: Where and how can I initialize them if my controller and query and arguments already exists? :/ i'm a bit new to coding I don't understand everything

Comment: in controller instead of 
$qb = $em->getRepository("STUserBundle:Operation")->getQueryByTypeAndPro($type, $user, $archive);
use 
$em->getRepository("STUserBundle:Operation")->findBy(array('type'=>here define value of type,'resellerId'=>here define value of resellerId,'archive'=>here define value of archive),array('dateCreation'=>DESC))

Comment: I guess its not as simple as I was thinking. Thank you for your help I will try to understand

Comment: just go through this link i hope it will help you https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database
and acknowledge my answer if it helps you

Comment: thank you for the link, but I think it not working quite like i want, I will continue searching